# How can i know the page from where slow query was hitting in MySQL in error log

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysql-slow-query-log

How can i know the page from where slow query was hitting in MySQL, like

```
"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id=123"
```

Lets say this query was written on page user.php and on many other pages and this query caught in slow log

Now i need to know the exact page on which this was run from error log

Comment: There is no easy way or magic that can find it for you

Answer (score 0):

Grep your source code for `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id=`.

Change the PHP code to include a comment (`/*...*/`) in each `SELECT` to say where it came from.  (If the slowlog strips comments, then add on `AND 'page5'='page5'` as a harmless, but useful, bit of info.)

Comment: Hi Rick, Thanks for the solution, it works for me and i successfully traced out page and again remove the code as you mention its little bit harmless.I would like to ask a question how its harmful?

Comment: The optimizer will have to parse the extra clause and throw it away.  The impact on performance will probably be less than 1%.

Comment: Thanks Rick for support.